# _popen: do not show the shell window (SW_HIDE)

Tags: c++, windows

When I execute the _popen command in c++ mfc it opens a shell window which I don't like, is it possible to make it hidden? for example when you try to execute commands with ShellExecute function it has the option to hide the shell window with SW_HIDE.

Comment: Why do you *want* to use `_popen`?

Comment: Here is a solution that works! https://stackoverflow.com/a/43600962/82856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(VS.80).aspx):

If used in a Windows program, the _popen function returns an invalid file pointer that causes the program to stop responding indefinitely. _popen works properly in a console application. To create a Windows application that redirects input and output, see [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx) in the Platform SDK.

Comment: You missed the next sentence in the doc: "_popen works properly in a console application."  From the question, it sounds like _popen is working -- just not as nicely as the OP would like.

Comment: He said "When I execute the _popen command in c++ mfc", and that sounds like windows app to me. I wouldn't use this function if I was in his place.