# hide console-window on executing _popen

Tags: c, winapi, popen

I hava a small c-tool in which i execute [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I compile the tool for windows and linux, in linux i use instead of [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the function [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html).

These functions work well and i can get the sub-process' output. But if i execute the function on windows ([`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) there's a cmd-window visible. On this window there's no ouput, but the window is visible.

Is there a way to block or hide this window?

best regards

Kevin Meier

Comment: You have a problem with Windows, not Linux. Tag removed.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910153/popen-do-not-show-the-shell-window-sw-hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call CreateProcess with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW
 flag. This is obviously non portable but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the handle of the console window, and then call [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx) to hide it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. If i compile my application with '-mwindows' (i use mingw to compile it) there's no difference, but if i compile the application with without it, your solution works. If i do it without '-mwindows', at the beginnig is the cmd-Window shown for a very short time. It's ok, but is there a way to compile the project with '-mwindows' and always hide the console?

Comment: @kevin: I am facing the same issue with popen has this issue got resolved.Please guide