# How to hide console windows when calling system()?

Tags: c++, windows

currently im using
system("\"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe\"");
to open up the virtual keyboard
and system("TASKKILL /IM TabTip.exe /F"); to kill it

its seems working but there is always a console window poping up
how can i get rid of that? thanks!

Comment: are you running them from a windows exe or console?

Comment: Use CreateProcess or ShellExecuteEx rather than system().  As a bonus, you'll also get a handle to the process so you can call TerminateProcess rather than shelling out to taskkill.

Comment: If you use console app and you get another console showing up you may try to use [popen](//stackoverflow.com/a/43536538/468725).

Answer (score 8):

Add below code in the beginning of your main, then create "TabTip.exe" with popen api. Because there is a hidden console in your app now, TabTip.exe created by the popen won't be shown.

```
AllocConsole();
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: I have searched a long time for this, and it works.  This deserves far more upvotes as this is a commonly asked question across SO and this is the only place I've seen a proper solution; instead people always respond with "use CreateProcess" which generally is a wall of code to get working proper.

Comment: Tips； #include<windows.h>